# How to get a joined volume Python Virtual environment to Airflow Docker working with external_python_task?

Tags: python, docker, airflow, airflow-2.x

## GOAL

- Have a local python environemnt that I can swap up and install things to it
- withouth needing to build a new image -> stopping the runing container -> starting new container

## DONE

- I use the docker version of airflow 2.4.1
- I have succesfully joined the Python Virtual environment to Airflow Docker as a volume you can see I in the docker-compose.yml
- After restarting docker with the new yml file it works fine.
- I can jump in to the container activate manually the python environment import and run python libraries perfectly fine.

## CHALLANGE

- The problem comes when I try to run my test dag with the new venv2
- The DAG works with the original external python environemnt that is installed via the Dockerfile but the goal would be to not to need this as mentioned before
- My guess is that this error happens because the python environemnt does not activated.

## Files and ERRORS

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-myown-image-apache/airflow:2.4.1}
  build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: NOTPUBLIC
    #ORIGINAL:                           postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    # For backward compatibility, with Airflow <2.3
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: NOTPUBLIC
    #ORIGINAL                       postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: NOTPUBLIC
    # ORIGINAL                       db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:1111/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: '' 
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKENDS: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.NOTPUBLIC'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
    AIRFLOW__CORE__ENABLE_XCOM_PICKLING: 'NOTPUBLIC'
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST: NOTPUBLIC
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PORT: 222
    AIRF LOW__SMTP__SMTP_USER: "NOTPUBLIC"
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PASSWORD: NOTPUBLIC
    AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_MAIL_FROM: NOTPUBLIC@NOTPUBLIC.com
    AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__BASE_URL: NOTPUBLIC
    AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__WEB_SERVER_SSL_CERT: /opt/airflow/certs/NOTPUBLIC.pem
    AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__WEB_SERVER_SSL_KEY: /opt/airflow/certs/NOTPUBLIC.pem
    AIRFLOW__CORE__MAX_ACTIVE_RUNS_PER_DAG: 1
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DEFAULT_TASK_EXECUTION_TIMEOUT: 21600
    AWS_SNOWPLOW_ACCESS_KEY: NOTPUBLIC
    AWS_SNOWPLOW_SECRET_KEY: NOTPUBLIC
    AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__MIN_FILE_PROCESS_INTERVAL: 180 
    #AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__DAG_DIR_LIST_INTERVAL: 600 
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - routtofolder/NOTPUBLIC1:/opt/airflow/NOTPUBLIC1
    - routtofolder/NOTPUBLIC2:/opt/airflow/NOTPUBLIC2
    - /routtofolder/NOTPUBLIC3:/opt/airflow/NOTPUBLIC3
    - ./venv2:/opt/airflow/venv2    #########################################THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC PART
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy
```

my example DAG that I want to work:

```
from __future__ import annotations

import logging
import sys
import tempfile
from pprint import pprint
from datetime import timedelta
import pendulum
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.models import Variable
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth



my_default_args = {
    'owner': 'Anonymus',
    'email': ['private@private.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
}


with DAG(
    dag_id='test_connected_env',
    schedule='10 10 * * *', 
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2021, 1, 1, tz="UTC"), 
    catchup=False,
    #execution_timeout=timedelta(seconds=60),
    default_args=my_default_args,
    tags=['sample_tag', 'sample_tag2'], 
    ) as dag:
    #@task.external_python(task_id="test_external_python_venv_task", python=os.fspath(sys.executable)) # ORIGINAL    
    #@task.external_python(task_id="test_connected_env_task", python='/opt/airflow/venv1/bin/python3') ### installed via pip via Dockerfile, this works perfectly fine
    @task.external_python(task_id="test_connected_env_task", python='/opt/airflow/venv2/bin/python3')
    def go(): # this could be any function name
        #import package here
        print("My Start") 
        #if you want to test the error
        # print(1+"Airflow")
        import pandas as pd
        print(pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6]}))

        import numpy as np
        print(np.array([1,2,3]))

        return print('my end')
        
        
    external_python_task = go()
```

ERROR that I get:

```
*** Reading local file: /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=test_connected_env/run_id=manual__2023-03-02T14:15:16.674123+00:00/task_id=test_connected_env_task/attempt=1.log
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1165} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: test_connected_env.test_connected_env_task manual__2023-03-02T14:15:16.674123+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1165} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: test_connected_env.test_connected_env_task manual__2023-03-02T14:15:16.674123+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1362} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1363} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1364} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1383} INFO - Executing <Task(_PythonExternalDecoratedOperator): test_connected_env_task> on 2023-03-02 14:15:16.674123+00:00
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {standard_task_runner.py:54} INFO - Started process 15812 to run task
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {standard_task_runner.py:82} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'test_connected_env', 'test_connected_env_task', 'manual__2023-03-02T14:15:16.674123+00:00', '--job-id', '142443', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/test_connected_env_task.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmp1t0wy5hy']
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {standard_task_runner.py:83} INFO - Job 142443: Subtask test_connected_env_task
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {dagbag.py:525} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /opt/airflow/dags/test_connected_env_task.py
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {task_command.py:384} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: test_connected_env.test_connected_env_task manual__2023-03-02T14:15:16.674123+00:00 [running]> on host 0ad620763627
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1590} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_EMAIL=NONPUBLIC@NONPUBLIC.NONPUBLIC
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=Anonymus
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=test_connected_env
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=test_connected_env_task
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2023-03-02T14:15:16.674123+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=1
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2023-03-02T14:15:16.674123+00:00
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {python.py:725} WARNING - When checking for Airflow installed in venv got Command '['/opt/airflow/venv2/bin/python3', '-c', 'from airflow import version; print(version.version)']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {python.py:726} WARNING - This means that Airflow is not properly installed by  /opt/airflow/venv2/bin/python3. Airflow context keys will not be available. Please Install Airflow 2.4.1 in your environment to access them.
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {process_utils.py:179} INFO - Executing cmd: /opt/airflow/venv2/bin/python3 /tmp/tmdqmf6q9rg/script.py /tmp/tmdqmf6q9rg/script.in /tmp/tmdqmf6q9rg/script.out /tmp/tmdqmf6q9rg/string_args.txt
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {process_utils.py:183} INFO - Output:
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {process_utils.py:187} INFO - My Start
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {process_utils.py:187} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {process_utils.py:187} INFO -   File "/tmp/tmdqmf6q9rg/script.py", line 38, in <module>
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {process_utils.py:187} INFO -     res = go(*arg_dict["args"], **arg_dict["kwargs"])
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {process_utils.py:187} INFO -   File "/tmp/tmdqmf6q9rg/script.py", line 30, in go
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {process_utils.py:187} INFO -     import pandas as pd
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {process_utils.py:187} INFO - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1851} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/decorators/base.py", line 188, in execute
    return_value = super().execute(context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 370, in execute
    return super().execute(context=serializable_context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 175, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 678, in execute_callable
    return self._execute_python_callable_in_subprocess(python_path, tmp_path)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 426, in _execute_python_callable_in_subprocess
    execute_in_subprocess(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/process_utils.py", line 168, in execute_in_subprocess
    execute_in_subprocess_with_kwargs(cmd, cwd=cwd)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/process_utils.py", line 191, in execute_in_subprocess_with_kwargs
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(exit_code, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/airflow/venv2/bin/python3', '/tmp/tmdqmf6q9rg/script.py', '/tmp/tmdqmf6q9rg/script.in', '/tmp/tmdqmf6q9rg/script.out', '/tmp/tmdqmf6q9rg/string_args.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {taskinstance.py:1401} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=test_connected_env, task_id=test_connected_env_task, execution_date=20230302T141516, start_date=20230302T141518, end_date=20230302T141518
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {warnings.py:109} WARNING - /home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py:120: RemovedInAirflow3Warning: Fetching SMTP credentials from configuration variables will be deprecated in a future release. Please set credentials using a connection instead.
  send_mime_email(e_from=mail_from, e_to=recipients, mime_msg=msg, conn_id=conn_id, dryrun=dryrun)

[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {email.py:229} INFO - Email alerting: attempt 1
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {email.py:241} INFO - Sent an alert email to ['NONPUBLIC@NONPUBLIC.com']
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {standard_task_runner.py:102} ERROR - Failed to execute job NONPUBLIC for task test_connected_env_task (Command '['/opt/airflow/venv2/bin/python3', '/tmp/tmdqmf6q9rg/script.py', '/tmp/tmdqmf6q9rg/script.in', '/tmp/tmdqmf6q9rg/script.out', '/tmp/tmdqmf6q9rg/string_args.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.; 15812)
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {local_task_job.py:164} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2023-03-02, 14:15:18 GMT] {local_task_job.py:273} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Comment: From your overall description, it doesn't seem like you need Docker; can you use a plain-Python virtual environment?

Comment: I do need docker for reasons I cannot mention here.